# Risks to quick vaccine development?

Tags: vaccination, death

I've heard that the longer a virus is in a population the less deadly it becomes. Something about deadliness being selected out from generation to generation.

Had me thinking that with the speed of vaccine development for Covid-19 that the virus may no longer have time to settle into that more benign phase.

Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Where did you hear this? This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, so citing a source for that statement would be a good place to start. Keep in mind that smallpox was known to the ancient Egyptians, and by the time it was finally eradicated in 1980 it still had a 30% death rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no rule about viruses getting weaker. In fact the original SARS-CoV-2 was less deadly than some of the newer variants.  In any case, SARS-CoV-2 has pretty much run rampant around the world even with the development of vaccines.